# Server for Push Notification?

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications

To build an iOS app that uses Apple's APN service, you need a server. Can this be any server e.g. Windows? Is this easier with Mac OS X Server Snow Leopard or does this even matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Server OS. You need a application that sends the messages to apples server. The "server" could run linux, windows or macos, or just could be any computer that is online. It's just the computer that runs the app.

What server would work best depends on the app that will send the messages. It might be written in ruby, php, java or whatever you want. I think there are librarys for several languages to help with sending those messages.